# How can I repeatedly borrow the variable outside the closure in different closures in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures

This is the core codes, which return the type of `Vec<(&'a str, i32)>`
**When I run this code,**

```rust
let mut i = 0;
contents.lines().filter(|x| {
    i += 1;
    x.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase())
}).map(|x|
    (x, i)
).collect()
```

**it alerts that:**

```
contents.lines().filter(|x| {
   |                             --- mutable borrow occurs here
56 |         i += 1;
   |         - first borrow occurs due to use of `i` in closure
57 |         x.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase())
58 |     }).map(|x|
   |        --- ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |        |
   |        mutable borrow later used by call
59 |         (x, i)
   |             - second borrow occurs due to use of `i` in closure
```

So how can I correct this code?

Comment: Note that if you think that by lowercasing the string you can compare it case-insensitively, you're wrong. Unicode is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to fix this code is to realize that what you're doing is essentially [`enumerate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) with index starting from 1 instead of zero, so either:

```rust
contents.lines().enumerate().filter(|(_, x)| {
    x.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase())
}).map(|(i, x)|
    (x, i + 1)
).collect()
```

Or:

```rust
contents.lines().zip(1..).filter(|(x, _)| {
    x.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase())
}).collect()
```

Comment: I think just switching to `filter_map` would also fix his issue, but certainly using `zip` like in your second example is much cleaner.

Comment: The second method works fine, while the first errors. value of type `Vec<(&str, i32)>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(&str, usize)>`

Comment: @TomZz Then your (unshown) code expects an `i32` and `enumerate()` gives a `usize`. You can cast, but it's better to use `zip()` anyway.

Comment: @PitaJ Feel free to submit an answer :)

Comment: Just change the first to (x , i as i32 + 1) is OK, but as the document of the enumerate says,  it is better to use zip instead of enumerate to return the types that isn't `usize`

Answer (score 1):

@Chayim Friedman
Thanks for your tips!
Now I could use the `filter_map` method to achieve my own aim and has learnt a skilled way to use the `zip`.

```
    let mut i = 0;
    contents.lines().filter_map(|x| {
        i += 1;
        if x.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) {
            Some((x, i))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).collect()
```